# My painted texture has disappeared

Tags: texturing

I painted an object, but the texture suddenly disappeared. I didn't save the texture before but I didn't close blender either. please is there any way to have the texture back?

Comment: Please add some more info about your specific situation, based on what you've supplied so far it would be very difficult for us to narrow down what you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

The texture file may not actually be gone. One way to check is in the Outliner, where at the very top left, you can select the "Blender File" display mode to see the entire contents of your project. Expand the "Images" category in the resulting list to see if your texture still exists in the project.

[image]

If you see it, then it probably just got unlinked from your object. In that case, you definitely don't want to close Blender, or the texture really will be lost. You would want to re-link it to your object in that case. You can do this by clicking the link button to the left of the current node name in either the *UV Editor* or the *Texture* tab of the Properties panel, under the *Settings* section.

[image]

Once re-linked, you still need to manually save the texture or else you'll still lose any progress made on it since it was first created.